# Detecting toucesbegan in uiscrollview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have added a vertical swipe to a horizontal scrollview. That bit works fine, but I would like to light up targets above and below the scrollview when the suer touches it, to indicate that swiping up or down causes an action.

How do I do that best?

Using a tap detector won't cut it, as it only fires once the finger is lifted.

Using a longpress detector with a short firing delay also won't work, as it seems to disable all the other gesture recognizers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grr... Why does this ALWAYS happen - just after you give up, the answer comes!

Yes, the longpress detector is the way to go for detecting start and end of the gesture BUT you need to implement the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol in a suitable object, and set it as delegate for all the gesture recognizers, then implement this method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

This keep the longpress detector from overriding all other gesture recognizers.

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass UIScrollView and override these methods:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

Comment: Good answer, but I found one that was a bit less work i think... See below.